# Changing the starting question number in examdesign

Tags: templates, counters

I'm trying to change the starting number for questions in an `examdesign` test.  I have to re-use scantrons throughout the semester, so I need to change the starting number on multiple choice problems. I've played around with `\setcounter{question}{50}` but it doesn't seem to have an effect. I know the way `examdesign` works with counters is odd because of the way it randomizes questions, but I can't figure out a way to get it to change the numbering start. I've also tried `\renewcommand` on the various counters, but not having much luck.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{examdesign}
\title{Exam}
\author{Examiner}
\date{Today}
\class{This One}
\begin{document}
  \begin{multiplechoice}
    \setcounter{question}{50}
      \begin{question} Here's my question
         \choice{First choice}
         \choice[!]{Second choice}
      \end{question}
   \end{multiplechoice}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Try `\setcounter{questionnumber}{50}`. I am getting a `LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.` when I try to compile your MWE.

Comment: I have done this with a different class. That is, I needed to do the same - reuse scantron sheets throughout the semester - and so I needed to start questions at the appropriate number. I did it with `exams.cls`. This is not in TeX Live because there is another package with the same name but it is on ctan. You just have to be careful of the name conflict for obvious reasons. I don't know if this is an option since I don't know what features of `examdesign` you are using.

Comment: @PeterGrill I tried sticking \setcounter with questionnumber and question as the counters in the preamble, after \begin{document} but before questions, and in the question itself, and it doesn't seem to have an effect. I also get that error (on the MWE and my actual test), but it compiles so I have just been dealing/ignoring it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the right trick...

First of all, the right counter is `questionnumber`. Before setting the counter you have to put

```
\resetcounterfalse
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{examdesign}
\title{Exam}
\author{Examiner}
\date{Today}
\class{This One}
\begin{document}
  \begin{multiplechoice}
    \resetcounterfalse
    \setcounter{questionnumber}{50}
      \begin{question} Here's my question
         \choice{First choice}
         \choice[!]{Second choice}
      \end{question}
   \end{multiplechoice}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @user47459 You're welcome. I don't know much of this document class, so, depending on the use, it might need some adjustments (e.g. some `\AtBeginEnvironment` commands). :-)

Comment: Fascinating. I found the right counter but I could not figure out how to prevent it resetting all the time!